# how to prevent object from casting shadow in scenekit?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

In scenekit you can remove an object from receiving light by setting its   categoryBitMask different than the the lights categoryBitMask

say the light has categoryBitMask=0001 and the node has categoryBitMask=0010, then the object will not be illuminated by the light.

But the object still throws a shadow on other objects from that light. How can I prevent an object from casting a shadow at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking for the [`castsShadow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407955-castsshadow) property on `SCNNode`